# Comparing mixed effect models

Tags: mixed-model

I'm trying to compare the performance of two models in explaining an outcome y.

E.g. mod1 <- lmer(y ~ A*time + (1|subj))

mod2 <-lmer(y~ B*time + (1|subj))

What would be the best way to compare and determine whether mod1 explains y better than mod2?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you'd put both A and B into the same model:

```
model<-lmer(y~A*time+B*time+(1|subj))
```

Then, you can compare the magnitude and significance of the  estimates of A and B and the relevant interactions.

If A and B are measured on different scales or represent different variable types, you'd want to get standardized estimates for comparison:

```
library(sjstats)
effectsize::standardize_parameters(model, method="pseudo")
```

You can also use model comparison to check whether model without A or B fits the data better:

```
model1<-lmer(y~A*time+B*time+(1|subj), data=df, REML=FALSE)
model2<-update(model1, .~. -A)
anova(model1, model2)
```